# Scrapy: star rating

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, css-selectors

I need to crawl this [page](https://www.healthgrades.com/physician/dr-victoria-harrison-25rcx). I need to get a star rating.

I have tried

```
len(response.css('.c-pes-wait-time+ .c-pes-officestaff-performance').css('li:nth-child(1) .filled').xpath('//*[has-class("hg3-i hg3-i-star-full")]'))
```

HTML

```html
<div class="c-pes-officestaff-performance">
      <div class="star-rating">
        <div class="empty">
          <span class="hg3-i hg3-i-star-full"></span>
          <span class="hg3-i hg3-i-star-full"></span>
          <span class="hg3-i hg3-i-star-full"></span>
          <span class="hg3-i hg3-i-star-full"></span>
          <span class="hg3-i hg3-i-star-full"></span></div>
        <div class="filled">
          <span class="hg3-i hg3-i-star-full"></span>
          <span class="hg3-i hg3-i-star-full"></span>
          <span class="hg3-i hg3-i-star-full"></span>
          <span class="hg3-i hg3-i-star-full"></span>
          <span class="hg3-i hg3-i-star-full"></span></div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your HTML on the site but this works for me (with Scrapy):

```
rating = response.xpath('//span[@data-id="js-section-review"]/button/span[1]/@aria-label').re_first(r'Rated (\d+)')
```